# SimpleDateFormat for past month, two months ago, three months ago

Tags: java, android, datetime

I am using SimpleDateFormat to get the current month but i want to show a recyclerview table with information of this month and past three months.

My php json loads this but i want to put automatically it in android.

```
    periodo1 = findViewById(R.id.tittle_periodo1);
    periodo2 = findViewById(R.id.tittle_periodo2);
    periodo3 = findViewById(R.id.tittle_periodo3);
    periodo4 = findViewById(R.id.tittle_periodo4);

    SimpleDateFormat month_date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMM");
    String month1 = month_date.format(c.getTime());
    periodo1.setText(month1);
```

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat` is used for date _formatting_, not for navigating dates. See the `Calendar` answer below and work from there.

Comment: @maksimov Nope. One shouldn't use `Calendar`, that class is obsolete. Instead, classes from the `java.time` package should be used. On Android API levels below 26, the ThreeTen AP Backport can be used.

Comment: Thanks, I know. I was hoping the author would become curious too - considering the comments below. Googling "Android LocalDate" gives you everything you need to know.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Calendar`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `YearMonth` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Yes, you can use it on Android. For older Android see [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
   Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(new Date());
    calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, -3); // -3 is Number of months past (july)
    Date newDate = calendar.getTime();
```

and you can format it if you want :

```
  String date = DateFormat.format("MM/dd/yyyy", newDate).toString();
```

Comment: A `CharSequence`??

Comment: `java.text.DateFormat#format` returns a `String`. There is no possible reason to downcast this object to a `CharSequence` here. Likewise, you shouldn't call `toString()` here, it does nothing. Also note that the author is already using `SimpleDateFormat`, and this isn't what their question is about.

Comment: Yes, you are right but I just want to give him the right answer!

Comment: @G.Romero please accept the answer that worked. It will help others with a similar question.

Answer (score 1):

With Java8 syntax you can use time library to achieve this

```
import java.time.LocalDate;

LocalDate now = LocalDate.now(); // 2019-11-01 (Nov)

LocalDate minusOneMonth = now.minusMonths(1); // 2019-10-01 
minusOneMonth.getMonth().getValue(); // Gives -1 month (10)

LocalDate minusTwoMonth = now.minusMonths(2); // 2019-09-01 
minusTwoMonth.getMonth().getValue(); // Gives -2 month (09)
```

Hope that's what you are looking for.

If you can't use Java8 syntax, use following

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(new Date());
    cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
    Date newDate = cal.getTime();

.... = new SimpleDateFormat("M")
```

Comment: Only on Android 8.0 and upwards

Comment: I have added 1 more way to my answer after reading your comment. Please check

Comment: This addition doesn't answer the question in any way.

Comment: i tried this but stopped while i was following comments, the solution is good too but i am using latest Xiaomi Redmi Note 7 to dev it and it gave me some warning messages. I apreciate your help!

Comment: @maksimov - Indeed Java 8 is not a syntax but if you really wish to fix English or Grammar, use edit function given by Stackoverflow instead of using a downvote. Another thing, author didn't mention java 5,6,7 or 8. So my answer doesn't become invalid. Last, another person had already added Calendar example, and hence I answere with dateformat initially but later I had to copy it too as I didn't know that people here will downvote quickly or point out language gaps. I didn't know I should double check grammar before posting here. :-) Anyways Thanks and Good luck 4 ur future –

Comment: For Android versions prior to 8.0 add ThreeTenABP to your project, change the import to `import org.threeten.bp.LocalDate;`, and it works. ThreeTenABP is the Android adaptation of the backport of java.time also known as JSR-310.

Comment: What warnings, please? @G.Romero The java.time code is definitely preferred over the code using the old and poorly designed `Calendar` class.